# Is there any option to pass parameters during a process to change status bar at tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have an application developed with tkinter, mostly all the data from all classes are build them by themself. Then I don't know have too many control over them, so as soon a create the class is analyzing, parsing, etc and filling all its atributes. So, I would like to show at status bar of tkinter how the process is going depending what my class is doing. I am a bit lost so I would like to know what could be the best option to do it, if it would not possible I will refactor in order to get it done, but I don't know what strategy to follow. Than

Comment: I suggest that you do the actual processing in another thread and leave the main thread for the status bar. You can have a shared variable that stores the progress of the process.

Comment: Could you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that its easier to relate to your requirement?